# Windows Phone emulator does not displays any animations/movement

Tags: animation, windows-phone-7.1, emulation, expression-blend

I prepared easiest app in the Blend4 I put the textBox in added story board, keyframe1, moved the textBox and add another keyframe. The animation works in the Blend4 i press play on the storyboard and the textBox moves. I run the emulator and it does not. I even ran app of my teacher it does not animate either(it should).

What I suppose to do to make it running?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you start animation from the code ??
F.E. flip animation:

XAML

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowBack" >
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="90"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackCover">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="90"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationZ)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="ShowFront" >
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="90"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontCover">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="90"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationZ)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackCover">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>


        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


<Image x:Name="FrontCover"   Source="{Binding TitleInfo.front_cover.Image}"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None" Margin="5">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform/>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                            <Image.Projection>
                                <PlaneProjection/>
                            </Image.Projection>
                                                               </Image>
                            <Image x:Name="BackCover"  Source="{Binding TitleInfo.back_cover.Image}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None" Margin="5" Visibility="Collapsed"  >
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform/>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                            <Image.Projection>
                                <PlaneProjection/>
                            </Image.Projection>

                            </Image>
```

CS code which start animation:

VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ShowBack", true);

Comment: How suppose I start it? I create it in blend's storyboard and it should run.

Comment: as i understend animation must start by some event.In Blend U run animation manual, pushing the play button. So how and when animation must start in the amulator. This article could help U http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Animations-in-depthndash-Overview-and-Getting-Started look at this example.